# probably squeeze theorem

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I need to find

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \left\lvert\sum_{k=1}^{2n} (-1)^k \sqrt[k]{k}\right\rvert.$$

I am nearly sure it has to be done using squeeze theorem. Unfortunatelly wasn't able to come up with solution.

I thought of something like

$$\frac{\sqrt{2} \: \frac{n}{2}- \frac{n}{2}\sqrt{2n-1}}{\sqrt{n}} \geq \dots \geq \frac{\frac{n}{2}\sqrt{2n} - \frac{n}{2}}{\sqrt{n}}.$$

But it's clearly wrong.

Comment: yeah, I am sorry

Comment: Hint: $\sqrt[k]{k} - 1$ decreases monotonically to $0$ when $k\geq 3$.

Comment: I dont know how to use that. Help me please.

Comment: $$
\sum\limits_{k = 1}^{2n} {( - 1)^k \sqrt[k]{k}}  = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{2n} {( - 1)^k (\sqrt[k]{k} - 1)}  + \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{2n} {( - 1)^k }  = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{2n} {( - 1)^k (\sqrt[k]{k} - 1)} ,
$$ and use the alternating series test (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test).

Comment: @Gary I think you should make your last comment an answer.

Comment: Can I somehow do that without alternating series test?

Comment: I have tried to improve the readability of your question by improving the [$\rm \LaTeX$](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189) code. It is possible that I unintentionally changed the meaning of your question.  Please proofread the question to ensure this has not happened.  It's better that you edit your question to include your last comment in the question body **before** getting an answer from someone.

Comment: I have changed the formatting of the title so as to [make it take up less vertical space](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9686/290189) -- this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main page is distributed evenly over the questions.  See [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9730/290189) for more information. Please take this into consideration for future questions. Thanks in advance.